# Export sheets specified in an array to separate pdf's

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, pdf

I'm trying to export sheets specified in an array to separate pdf's.
My code doesn't look through the array specified.

```
Sub ExportToPDFs()
   
    Dim outFldr As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Variant, sheets_to_select As Variant

    outFldr = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    sheets_to_select = (Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))

    For Each i In sheets_to_select
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
          Filename:=outFldr & "\" & i & ".pdf", _
          Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
          IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Drop the outer parentheses, and use `LBound` and `Ubound` to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the code naming the variables to something more readable

and fixed the a couple of things

- The way you assigned the items to the array
- The loop (for)

Code:

```
Sub ExportToPDFs()
   
   Dim outputFolderPath As String
   Dim currentWorksheet As Worksheet
   Dim counter As Long
   Dim sheetsIndexArr As Variant
   
   ' Define the folder path
   outputFolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path ' Check if this could be ThisWorkbook
   
   ' Define the indexes of sheets to be exported
   sheetsIndexArr = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
   
   For counter = LBound(sheetsIndexArr) To UBound(sheetsIndexArr)
   
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets(counter).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=outputFolderPath & "\" & counter & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
   
   
   Next counter

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Richard, apologies for not getting back to you, but yes that worked very well. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Awesome Jason. If it helped, remember to mark the answer (tick at the left) so others may find it too :)